# How dismiss keyboard without losing focus. or at least show cursor

Tags: ios, objective-c

How dismiss **keyboard** without losing focus. or at least show cursor.

I have speech recognition button and textview. 
User can type with keyboard or  use speech recognition. 
But I want to dismiss keyboard while user using speech recognition.

Currently, I am resigning responder but it hides cursor on textView.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I think the situation is different between my question and that one

Comment: sorry, on that time you are not clearly mentioned the question , ok are you close and reopen the question ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved these with following steps:

1) I subclassed `UIWindow` and override `sendEvent`
Inside:
I check for tap presence and do following if view is intended one

```
UITextView *view=(UITextView*)touch.view;
view.input=nil;
[view reloadInputViews];
```

**This way I ensure that on tap Keyboard will appear for my textview**

2) For my speech recognition button click I do following to hide default keyboard

```
myview.input=[[UIView alloc]init];
 [myview reloadInputViews];
```